# Currency conversion for NxN currencies in SSMS

Tags: ssms

I have a table (say A) that gives me currency conversion from a currency to USD. Lets say I have 3 currencies for now.

[image]

using this table I want to create the following output table (say B).

[image]

For example, AED to ARS would be 3.67/18.87 = .19

Imagine I have 70 from currencies in table A. This becomes hard to calculate manually. I am trying to do this in SSMS.

Would be great to have an approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the combination of all exchange values by taking a cartesian product of the table with itself. We can use **CROSS JOIN** for the same.

As the toCurrency is USD in all cases, we can directly divide the 'from' values of the 2 tables to derive other combinations of from and to Currencies. An example snippet of code is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS currencyExchangeBase
CREATE TABLE currencyExchangeBase ( fromCode varchar(3),
                                             toCode varchar(3),
                                                    exchangeValue numeric(19, 2) )
INSERT INTO currencyExchangeBase
VALUES ('AED','USD',3.67),('ARS','USD',18.87), ('AUD','USD',1.28205);


SELECT b1.fromCode AS fromCode,
       b2.fromCode AS toCode,
       b1.exchangeValue/b2.exchangeValue AS exchangeValue
FROM currencyExchangeBase b1
CROSS JOIN currencyExchangeBase b2
```

Comment: sorry if my question wasn't clear. I am saying my output should be Table B, hence I want a logic to create it.

Comment: Exactly, you will get the second table, with the logic mentioned above. Just try the snippet of the code and just change the column names and table name.